# Specific link doesn't open in Excel when you click on it

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a clickable link https://etf.com in an Excel cell. But when I click it, it doesn't open and instead show an error `The site reports that the request is not valid.`

[image]

Andy idea why this happens? It is reproducible on multiple machines.

Comment: Maybe Excel regex expects a `www.` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is reproduced on my test environment with Microsoft 365 apps installed.

After I [add the Internet Subkey to the registry](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/cannot-locate-server-when-click-hyperlink#add-the-internet-subkey-to-the-registry-and-set-the-value-data), I can open the website in Excel.
My Windows and Office both are 64-bit, so according to the link, I add the following registry key.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Common\Internet
Type: DWORD
Name: ForceShellExecute
Value Data: 1
```

[image]

[image]

Serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Before you modify it, [back up the registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322756) for restoration in case problems occur.