# Error Message with Pasted Hyperlink in MS Word 2010 Document, When Same Hyperlink Works Fine Pasted into Web Browser

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, hyperlink, embedded

Normally I don't have any problems with embedded or pasted hyperlinks working in MS Word 2010; however there is one which is giving me problems.  The hyperlink is: https://creativemarket.com/account/purchases and should take user to login screen for the "Creative Market" website (where their username and password should be entered to then access their account information).  When I paste this hyperlink into a MS Word 2010 document and then click on it, I get the error message "Unable to open https://aeativemarket.com/account/purchases. Cannot download the information you requested (screenshot of error message is pasted below, for your reference). [image]  However, when I copy that exact same non-working hyperlink in Word document and copy and paste it into my web browser (Chrome), it works fine, and takes me to the Creative Market user account login page (as desired).
I have uploaded my MS Word 2010 file to my Google Docs drive, with permission for anyone to download, in case someone wants to download it and see exactly how the error message occurs when the link is clicked in the documents.  The link is clearly pasted (under a graphical header I created), and the link is also embedded in this graphical header, and gives me the same error message, when the hyperlinked graphical header is clicked.  The Google Docs address for the document is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bchpbZWrongMWKjSz9HI8w7a5fPrqNti/view?usp=sharing.
Why would this hyperlink work when pasted into a browser, but not when pasted into a MS Word document and then clicked?  I also tried creating a new MS Word 2010 document with this hyperlink pasted in it (just to make sure it wasn't a specific document problem, and still the pasted hyperlink (into the Word document) does not work and gives me the same error message, when clicked.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks, in advance, for your input and help.
-Cfguy

Answer (score 0):

The similar issue as "[Specific link doesn't open in Excel when you click on it](https://superuser.com/questions/1638833/specific-link-doesnt-open-in-excel-when-you-click-on-it)".

Please [add the Internet Subkey](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/cannot-locate-server-when-click-hyperlink#add-the-internet-subkey-to-the-registry-and-set-the-value-data) to the registry. As my Windows 10 and Office 2010 both are 64-bit, I add the following registry key as before. (Just in case，before you modify it, it's recommended to [back up the registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322756) for restoration.)

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Common\Internet`

`Type: DWORD`

`Name: ForceShellExecute`

`Value Data: 1`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Emily - thanks for addressing my question.  I opened my registry to attempt the addition that you suggested only to find that I already had an entry "ForceShellExecute" with a type of "REG_QWORD" with the data value the same as you suggested "0x00000001 (1)".  Here is a link to an image of the screenshot of what I found in my registry at that spot: https://ibb.co/fNCYqbf. At this point, should I continue to add the subkey that you suggested, or should I delete the "REG_QWORD" entry that is already there, before I add the "REG_DWORD" entry that you suggested?  Thanks so much for your help.