# Error Message with Pasted Hyperlink in MS Word 2010 Document- Should I Replace QWORD Registry Entry with DWORD?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, windows-registry, hyperlink

I previously posted a question   The original post (and response) can be found by clicking: https://superuser.com/a/1658665 (link goes right to proposed answer in my original post).  The person that answered my question recommended that I add an internet subkey to the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Common\Internet
Type: DWORD
Name: ForceShellExecute
Value Data: 1
```

Problem is, when I opened my registry and went to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Common\Internet`, I found that I already had a subkey of the following:

```
Type: QWORD
Name: ForceShellExecute
Value Data: 1
```

Notice my existing subkey is a "QWORD", whereas the person who replied to my original post wanted me to create a "DWORD" subkey, with essentially the same values.

I answered her reply and let her know about the already present "QWORD" subkey; however I don't think that she ever read the reply, as it has been almost a month without another reply from her.

I did reopen "regedit", went back to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Common\Internet" and tried to add a "DWORD" subkey (to accompany my existing "QWORD" subkey); however when I attempt to add to "DWORD" subkey I receive the following "Error Renaming Value" message: "The Registry Editor cannot rename New Value #1. The specified value name already exists. Type another name and try again."

Since the values are the same, is my existing "QWORD" subkey essentially the same thing as the replier's proposed "DWORD" entry, therefore making the proposed "DWORD" subkey just a duplicate of what I already have as a "QWORD" subkey?  Or should I try deleting my existing "QWORD" subkey, and then adding the proposed "DWORD" subkey - might this make a difference in solving my original problem "Error Message with Pasted Hyperlink in MS Word 2010 Document, When Same Hyperlink Works Fine Pasted into Web Browser"?

Additionally, if deleting my existing "QWORD" subkey and replacing it with the proposed "DWORD" subkey will not make any difference in solving my original problem, are there any other steps that I may try to solve my original problem?

Answer (score 0):

### DWORD and QWORD entries are for 32-bit and 64-bit installations of Word, respectively.

I do not believe Windows will let you add the wrong one.

**For Word 2010, you would want to be adding to Office 14, not Office 9.**

[image: screenshot of registry editor]

See: [What version of Word do I have?](https://shaunakelly.com/word/management/what-version-of-word-do-i-have.html) by Word MVP Shauna Kelly. (Word 2016-2019 and Word 365 are all under Version 16.